# All rows in UILabel not visible depending on text

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, swift

I have a label that goes across the screen with a margin of 20 on each side and the line attribute is set to 0

This is what it looks like in Interface Builder

[image]

There is no problem if the text fits on a single row but if it needs another row, then the second row isn't always visible.

If I use the text and the image above, then the result looks like this in the simulator

[image]

But if I add some more text then the second row is visible.
Interface Builder:

[image]

iOS Simulator:

[image]

Am I missing something with the constraints?

You can download the project [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6498500/label.zip) and try for yourself. I've added a textview and a button to easier debug it.

Comment: In your screenshots, the frames are orange, indicating that they are not reflecting the position on screen as defined by the constraints. Make sure all is "blue".

Comment: I did that, still the same problem. Not with the same text though.

Comment: I updated the linked project.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the desired height in code. It's just a few lines.

https://gist.github.com/danielphillips/1005520
credit DanielPhillips

Comment: Hmm okay, how would you do that in Swift?

Comment: The up to date API `boundingRectWithSize` is only available for Objective-C. Just include the subclass in the bridging header.